# Utilizar una variable en todas mis funciones

Tags: funciones, php7, variables, variables-globales

me pueden ayudar con lo siguiente, tengo un método en el que necesito declarar una variable $x = 0; y esta variable poder modificarla dentro de los métodos de mi archivo php, como puedo hacerlo ?

```
<?php


class ClaseEjemplo 
{
    $x = 0;
    $y = 2;

    public function primeraFuncion()
    {
        $x = $x+$y;
    }

    public function segunbdaFuncion()
    {
        echo $x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al estar encapsulado en una clase, puedes declarar atributos de clase que pueden ser utilizados en cualquier función de la clase. En tu ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php


class ClaseEjemplo 
{
    public $x = 0;
    public $y = 2;

    public function primeraFuncion()
    {
        $this->x = $this->x+$this->y;
    }

    public function segunbdaFuncion()
    {
        echo $this->x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero excelente tu respuesta me queda clasisimo